# Перенаправится ли вывод обратно в стандартный вывод?

Tags: python

Хочу перенаправить вывод ошибок в файл. В то время, пока я нахожусь в пределах блока первого контекстного менеджера - всё нормально (`sys.stderr = file`), но что происходит в системе, когда этот блок заканчивается? 
После кода:

```
with open("startlog.log", "a") as file:
    sys.stdout = file
    sys.stderr = file
    ...
```

У меня следует код:

```
log_file_name = 'путь'
with open(log_file_name, "w") as file:
    sys.stdout = file
```

stderr не перенаправляю никуда. Перенаправляется ли `sys.stderr = в консоль`? Или нужно это явно прописать где-то?

Comment: Если вам нужна поддержка логов, хоть в файл, хоть в БД, хоть в `syslog`, хоть в `stdout/stderr`, воспользуйтесь встроенным модулем `logging`. Он решает, как вашу проблему, так и массу проблем, о которых вы пока не подумали.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо создания велосипеда, для перенаправления вывода советую использовать [contextlib](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.redirect_stdout):

```
from contextlib import redirect_stdout, redirect_stderr

with open("startlog.log", "a") as f:
    with redirect_stdout(f), redirect_stderr(f):
        help(pow)

        print('\n')

        import sys
        print("ERROR!!!", file=sys.stderr)
```

---

А так, ваш код с заменой `stdout` и `stderr` внутри `with` приведет к тому, что ссылки на стандартные потоки вывода будут переписаны ссылкой на файловый поток, а `with` закроет файловый поток. Из-за чего `stdout` и `stderr` перестанут работать (как и `file`)

```
import sys

with open("startlog.log", "a") as file:
    sys.stdout = file
    sys.stderr = file
    ...
```

Поэтому, нужно руками сохранять потоки вывода и после восстанавливать на них ссылки:

```
import sys

prev_stdout = sys.stdout
prev_stderr = sys.stderr

with open("startlog.log", "a") as file:
    sys.stdout = file
    sys.stderr = file

    ...

sys.stdout = prev_stdout
sys.stderr = prev_stderr
```